# Github Workflow jobs are split into two groups in Summary view

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to improve my Github actions skills, and I'm currently writing an advanced workflow (composed of smaller reusable workflows) to deploy a test app to production. As part of that, this is what I'm doing:

- **Run CI jobs in parallel**

  - Run Lint
  - Run Unit Tests
  - Run E2E Tests
- **Request Approval from code owners**

  - Wait for approval using [`trstringer/manual-approval`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval)
- **Deploy App**

  - Build and deploy docker image to hosting service

Now the entire workflow does actually work as expected, following all the steps in the right order.

---

## My Issue

**My issue is that three jobs in the first `CI` workflow are split into two groups in the "Summary" view, when it should have just been one group.**

*(I know, I know -- first world developer problems)*

| Sidebar | Summary Diagram |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Sidebar Image] | [image: Summary Diagram] |

In the summary screenshot above, the `test:e2e` job is shown in a separate group/box for some reason, when it should have been in the box with the other two `CI` jobs. But in the sidebar screenshot, they are still grouped together.

---

## Code Organization

I have two repos with actions, organized as follows:

#### Repo 1: `testorg/devops`

- This repo is for common workflows that I want to share across multiple projects
- It currently has two workflows:

  - `request-approval`
  - `deploy`
- Both workflows work as expected without issues

#### Repo 2: `testorg/myapp`

- This is the app that I am trying to setup CI/CD for production
- This app uses both of the shared workflows from `testorg/devops`
- It currently has three workflows:

  - `ci`

    - This workflow is run automatically on every PR
    - It defines the `lint`, `test:unit`, and `test:e2e` jobs
  - `deploy-stage`

    - It is run automatically on every commit on the `main` branch
    - It uses the `ci` workflow above, followed by the `deploy` workflow from devops
  - `deploy-prod`

    - It can only be run manually using `workflow_dispatch`
    - It uses the `ci` workflow above, followed by `request-approval` and `deploy` workflows from devops
  - Both deployment workflows face the same problem but it does not happen in the `ci` workflow.

| CI Workflow | Deploy Staging Workflow |
| --- | --- |
| [image: CI Workflow] | [image: Deploy Stage Workflow] |

---

## Workflow Code

As a minimal example here, I will focus on the `ci` and `deploy-stage` workflows since they are all we need to reproduce the issue:

#### `myapp/deploy-stage.yml`

```yaml
name: Deploy Staging

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ 'main' ]

jobs:
  ci:
    name: CI
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci.yml

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to Staging
    needs: ci
    uses: testorg/devops/.github/workflows/deploy.yml@main
    with:
      APP_ENV: stage
    secrets: inherit
```

#### `myapp/ci.yml`

```yaml
name: CI


on:
  workflow_call:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ 'main' ]


env:
  NODE_VERSION: '18.6.0'
  DB_NAME: app_test
  DB_USER: postgres
  DB_PASS: postgres


jobs:

  lint:
    name: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run Linter
        run: yarn lint


  unit_tests:
    name: test:unit
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: ${{ env.DB_NAME }}
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{ env.DB_USER }}
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ env.DB_PASS }}
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: yarn test:unit


  e2e_tests:
    name: test:e2e
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: ${{ env.DB_NAME }}
          POSTGRES_USER: ${{ env.DB_USER }}
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{ env.DB_PASS }}
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Run E2E Tests
        run: yarn test:e2e
```

Here's the code for other workflows:

#### `devops/deploy.yml`

```yaml
name: Deploy to Fly.io

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      APP_ENV:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      FLY_API_TOKEN:
        required: true

env:
  APP_ENV: ${{ inputs.APP_ENV }}
  FLY_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FLY_API_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: superfly/flyctl-actions/setup-flyctl@master
      - run: fly deploy --remote-only
```

#### `devops/request-approval.yml`

```yaml
name: Request Approval

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  request:
    name: Request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Wait for approval
        uses: trstringer/manual-approval@v1
        timeout-minutes: 60
        with:
          approvers: user1,user2,user3
          minimum-approvals: 1
          issue-title: ""
          issue-body: |
            New production deployment requested by @${{ github.triggering_actor }}.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how that is an issue for you? What is the problematic part? Just asking, because for me it looks like everything is totally fine and in order and I'd like to better understand your question / problem statement.

Comment: The only thing I could spot is a `uses:` property referring to a workflow, but IIRC it must be an action. Despite that, the execution graph looks forgiving to me as everything that should be executed is executed, at least how I understand it, see my previous comment.

Comment: I want the summary view to have all three jobs in one box. I can't understand why the summary graph is splitting the jobs of the workflow into two boxes/group.

Comment: Apart from one box with three, from the functionality standpoint (not display), the outcome is already correct for you, right? I'm asking for clarification not neglecting what you're after and to better understand your issue.

Comment: @hakre `uses` with a workflow is valid, that's how you call a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

Comment: Yes functionally it works as expected.

Comment: After messing around with the workflows more since yesterday, I am starting to think this is a bug with Github. In a later re-run with the same code, they were grouped together, but in another re-run, it's back to being separate. I've diffed the workflow changes but nothing was really different.